# Cpanel Permission when uploading

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

When I upload files through my cpanels file manager all my php file permissions are being changed to 0666 from what I read this is not secure + it is causing my WordPress to not function correctly. Normally web hosts have the permissions set to 0644 when uploading files. It would takes ages for me to change all files manually from 0666 to 0644. How can I change the permissions when I upload in cpanel? Should I try ftp and see if that makes a difference?

**EDIT**

When I upload the zip file it uploads as 0644 than when I extract the files inside are all turned into 0666.

Thanks

Comment: you can change permission of all files using FTP, no need to re-upload files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to re-upload all files to simply change permission for them.

Use your FTP client to change file permissions for files, directories and sub-directories.

You can do this via command-line SSH (if you have access).

Comment: Would I have to go into each folder and edit the permission for each file? I do not have SSH access. I think you are correct through FTP is the way to go. I was uploading a zip file and unzipping. When I unzip is when the files get changed to 0666. I'll try FTPing all the files over.

Comment: @hubvill no you don't. Regardless of which FTP client you'll end up using, they all will support changing file permissions for folders, files inside these folders and sub-folders or also known as _recursive file permission change_.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the problem and thought I would share. When I tried unzipping the file locally and during the unzipping process I received a popup telling me there is a duplicate file. So I clicked yes to overwrite the file. Created a new zip file from the newly extracted files uploaded it to the server, extracted it and boom all the files have 0644 permissions.

Comment: Hi @hubvill. It would have been much easier to use FTP client and simply change permission recursively. Going forward I highly recommend to use FTP client instead of CPanel for any type of work with server files/directories.

Answer (score 0):

The way that fixed my problem was this one :

**I had access to Terminal**

Consider that i have a folder named "Storage" on my public_html folder.
i should open public_html folder on Terminal, then i just need to write this code on terminal:

```
chmod 755 Storage -R
```

That's it!

for some young eyes, you should see something like this on your terminal :

```
[user@blahblah public_html]$ chmod 755 Storage -R
```